# Can I use target="" somehow -- or do I have to use javascript to satisfy this requirement?

Tags: javascript, html, window, launch

I have a page with numerous links to several external applications.  The requirement is to have all the applications launch into a new window--but ONLY ONE new window.  In other words if the user goes back go the link page any new launch needs to go to just the same one (already launched) window.

Is there no way to use basic HTML to do this or do I have to use javascript? target="_blank" or target="_new" obviously launches a new window with each click.  I'm in kind of a weird environment here so I can't use JQuery, and a lot of added scripts tend to conflict with whats going on, so basic HTML would be ideal.

Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something and that this can't be done with just HTML.  Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `target="_blank"` it opens new tab not new window!

Comment: @AspiringAqib whether it opens in a new tab or new window depends on user agent settings.

Comment: @kojiro that is right! but by default it is for new tab but was for new window when tabs were not introduced :P (in ancient IE)

Comment: @AspiringAqib Not for lynx.

Comment: Well, What is This? `lynx` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `target="myexternalapplications"` to create or reuse a window with the name "externalapplications". For target, the values _blank, _top are just specials.